# adb sync .. over wifi...?

Tags: adb, android-source

I am developing an Android firmware, and I don't have a USB connection between the Linux machine and my board  (the Linux machine I use is remote on my LAN, and I connect to it via SSH).

What my team is currently doing is mapping the android source directory (and OUT) as a Windows share, and the  use `fastboot flash *.img` to flash the created images from windows.

I am used to use `adb sync` to sync the locally modified files to the device, but when you do this from windows `/system/bin/sh` will not get the executable bit (for example) and the board will fail to boot.

I was thinking of doing "adb sync" over the network from the remote linux server, is this possible?

Comment: It may be possible by modifying adb.c and commandline.c in Android source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=623828&page=3) on xda-developers, you can enable ADB over WiFi from the device with the commands:

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

And you can disable it and return ADB to listening on USB with commands:

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port -1
stop adbd
start adbd
```

If you have USB access already, it is even easier to switch to using WiFi. From a command line on the computer that has the device connected via USB, issue the commands:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect <ip_address_of_mobile_device>:5555
```

To tell the ADB daemon return to listening over USB:

```
adb usb
```

EDIT:
On newer Android versions you can set the listening from the settings menu. I did not test it with "sync" but "shell" and debugging work.

Comment: I am using this to connect to my phone and develop using AndroidStudio. I did not test it to do a full "adb sync" but I don't think this will fail.. just work slow... :)